Assigning css style in type script using setAttribute
I am trying to assign element's attributes in typescript using setAttribute like this w3school example
Here is my JavaScript:
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.setAttribute('class', 'demoClass');
p.innerText = 'Hello';

and .css:
.demoClass {
  background-color: #00ffff !important;  
}

But this way it doesn't take the style.
The only solution I've found is the following:
p.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #00ffff !important');

Does anyone know how I can give the style using the class and not directly assigning it? Thank you in advance.
Update:
This code works fine as typescript, see here: here
But not in an angular project, see here

Why is your question tagged with angular?

Are you sure your CSS is loaded on your page correctly?

Oh my very bad, noope I had forgotten to add styleUrl .

But even adding the .css file, setting class neither by classList.add nor setAttribute doesn't works.

@user6781 can you make a [mcve]? (without using Angular)

@PetəíŕdtheWizard sorry it took a moment, here: https://github.com/EftePA/setClassAttribute you can find a javascrit version of my code.

@user6781 it all works fine for me. Either way, I usually try to load CSS before the <body> and insert any <script>s in the end of the <body>.

If you mean you don't see the .highlighter being rendered, that's because it's empty.

No the p element. I have the feeling some extra step is required for angular project. You can see my update. From the beginning the code was working in javascript, but only when I change it to angular, then it stops.

@user6781 Oh, so that's the problem. You could edit your question again including the [tag:angular] tag. Unfortunately, I'm not an Angular expert, but I'll let you know if I find the solution for this.

Can you show us a snippet of code that demonstrates the problem. At the moment you haven’t shown us how you add the element to the DOM.

are you as well appending your p element ? ie document.body.appendChild(p). Because it should work properly. Also check if your css is also loaded properly as @Nick Parsons said

Yes @Mehdi I am appending it.

@AHaworth What do you mean by showing the problem? I have a code that works in javascript, but when I use it in an angular project then it doesn't work. It is just about a simple background color, the PROBLEM is that the color is not applied.

I understand that the color isn't applied, we need to see code that demonstrates that. What you have shown so far doesn't show the problem - as you say the problem occurs in an angular environment.

You should use classList, not setAttribute:
const p = document.createElement('p');
p.classList.add("your-class");
// do whatever you need with the new p

Replace the your-class with the class that you need to add.

It doesn't work.

How it doesn't work? Do you actually insert the new element anywhere?

Yes it is inserted and I see the Hello but the background is transparent. Just to clarify, setAttribute works in javascript, but I have copied it in my angular project. Should I change something else or it should work in typescript as well?

It should work in typescript, just make sure you use your own class instead of your-class. @user6781

Can you show us a snippet of code that demonstrates the problem. At the moment you haven’t shown us how you add the element to the DOM.

Your app component does not load at all, here is a project I setuped to make it work: here
so i had to use AfterViewInit, so I can get the element by id, ngOnInit is not a good approach, bcs nothing is loaded yet.
Also you must use ViewEncapsulation.None, The reason lies in how Angular's ViewEncapsulation works. By default, Angular scopes component styles to ensure that they do not "leak" into other components or the global DOM. Another approach is to use global CSS within file styles.css then you do not need to set ViewEncapsulation to none
